# Is the phenomenom of “subjective consciousness” or “qualia” formally captured by any state-of-the-art Theoretical Model in Neuroscience?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, consciousness, theory-of-mind, qualia

Is the phenomenon of "subjective consciousness" or "[qualia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia)" formally captured or defined by any state-of-the-art Theoretical Model in Neuroscience? If so, can you share a brief summary of such formalization and references for further reading?

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10364/7001

Comment: Unsure if this is related or if I should explain the relevance in a separate answer https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/10429/4397

Comment: Look into IIT,  Integrated Information Theory.